# How to include external sources in .NET Core MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, .net-core

In the Preview 2 .NET Core SDK (`project.json`), one could include external sources just by adding them to global.json, e.g. replacing MVC with downloaded sources:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test", "../mvc" ]
}
```

With the .NET Core SDK 1.0.0 RC4, solution metadata is back in the `.sln` file, and you can add projects and NuGet packages using `dotnet add`, but there is apparently no way to add an external folder as in the previous SDK version.

How could I add e.g. MVC source so they are used instead of the NuGet packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Damian Edwards on [this ASP.NET Community Standup episode](https://youtu.be/qlVE5iDjBIg), this functionality did not make it with the shift to MSBuild, although they have not forgotten about the scenario, so the concept might make it back in another form in the future.